# Prevent changes to styles in Powerpoint

Tags: styles, powerpoint

I work at a company with a nice corporate Powerpoint template.

That doesn't stop "creative" people from change fonts, colors, etc.

Is there a way to disable this? To prevent style/template changes. If the font defined in the master slide is verdana, we don't want people changing this to comic sans in the actual slide.

Answer (score 0):

To some extent, this kind of thing can be handled by custom-written add-ins; there's no way to do it "out of the box" in PowerPoint.

Preventing the horse from wandering off the path is almost impossible in PPT.
Better to consider ways of making the path you want the horse to take as easy/pleasant/unimpeded as possible (and rely on training to encourage people to do what you want).